# AWS Cloud Formation for Tomcat with Fargate

Tags: tomcat, aws-fargate

We are trying to bring up a web app running on a Tomcat server and Postgres with two Fargate containers. Trying to use a simple, direct setup without load balancers.

The cloud formation script successfully runs, but does not appear to create running apps.

The resources in my YAML are:

ECSTaskExecutionRole
ECSCluster
CloudWatchLogsGroup
ContainerSecurityGroup
Task

[image]
Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you seen any error in Cloudformation events?

Comment: There are no errors in the cloud formation events.

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems, first I needed to configure a Service, after doing that the Service would appear to hang and the stack would rollback after the default timeout of 3 hours.

Checking the service tasks, there was no log, but there was an error msg

```
Status reason CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: Get https://<container-uri>/v2
```

It seems the ECS service task's security group's rules didn't allow pulling the image.

https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/1128